# Binding the selected value from a combobox to a member of a class

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a combobox that is bound to a an instance of a class.  I need to get the user's selection ID of the combobox and set a class property equal to it.

For example, here is the class:

```
public class robot
{
    private string _ID;
    private string _name;
    private string _configFile;
    [XmlElement("hardware")]
    public hardware[] hardware;

    public string ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }
    }
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public string configFile
    {
        get { return _configFile; }
        set { _configFile = value; }
    }
}
```

Now here is the code to bind the combobox to an instance of that class.  This display's the name of each robot in the array in the combobox.

```
    private void SetupDevicesComboBox()
    {
        robot[] robot = CommConfig.robot;
        cmbDevices.DataSource = robot;
        cmbDevices.DisplayMember = "name";
        cmbDevices.ValueMember = "ID";
    }
```

But now I can't seem to take what the user selects and use it.  How do I use the "ID" of what the user select's from the combobox?

```
Settings.selectedRobotID = cmbDevices.ValueMember;  //This just generates "ID" regardless of what is selected.
```

I also tried

```
Settings.selectedRobotID = cmbDevices.SelectedItem.ToString();  //This just generates "CommConfig.robot"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Settings.selectedRobotID = ((robot)cmbDevices.SelectedItem).ID;
```

Comment: Cool that worked.  I found that this also worked.

Settings.selectedRobotID = cmbDevices.SelectedValue.ToString();